# addClass if ul exists (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm building a simple dropdown where I'd like to add a class to parent if UL exists:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So I'd like to:

- hide all nested (`ul#menu > li > ul`) ul's initially
- show/hide nested `ul` on hover
- addClass "dropdown" to parents that have nested ul's

This isn't quite working, not sure why:

```
$(function () {
    $("ul#menu li").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("ul#menu li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").addClass("dropdown");
});
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ul = $('#menu');

if (ul.length) {
    ul.children('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    }).children('ul').hide().parent().addClass('dropdown');
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ofayu

BTW: you are closing the `<li>` tags incorrectly in your markup.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
$("ul#menu li ul li:has(ul)")
```

Given your HTML structure, shouldn't this be:

```
$("ul#menu li:has(ul)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* do the trick (untested):

```
$('ul#menu > li > ul').each(function()
{
    var list = $(this);
    list.hide();
    list.parent().hover(list.hide, list.show);
    list.parent().parent().addClass('dropdown');
});
```

Comment: You cannot hover over a hidden item.

Comment: Good call; I guess the hover needs to be on the list item.